# How to use Github Oauth for Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, authentication, express

I've cut and paste every block of code from the instructions from both Github, the npm modules and similar questions here on SO. One way or another, the solutions aren't working out. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, Nodejs Express, and Postgresql. I think I just have no idea what I'm doing right now. Here's the error I'm currently getting:
[image: Terminal Error Message]

I'm inclined to believe there's something wrong with my code here and that this error is due to that rather than a failing of the actual modules. I've reported it to the authors anyway just in case. Here's the code from app.js:

```
// POSTGRESQL AUTHORIZATION FUNCTION
var findOrCreate = function(username,id) {
if (db.query("SELECT EXISTS(select username from users where github_id="+id)) {
    passport.authenticate('local');
    res.redirect('/', { user: req.user });
} else {
    db.query("INSERT INTO users (username, github_id) VALUES ($1, $2)"), [username, id], function(err, res) {
        if (!err) {
            passport.authenticate('local');
            res.render('/', { user: req.user });
        }
        console.log(err);
    };
}
};

// GITHUB AUTHENTICATION
passport.use(new GitHubStrategy({
    clientID: GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:5000/auth/github/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
        console.log("Access Token: " + accessToken);
        console.log(profile.username);
        findOrCreate(profile.username, profile.id);
        return done(null, profile);
    });
}));
```

In the console of Google Chrome I'm getting a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` when trying to login using Github.

I'm trying to authorize login through Github, check the Github credentials against the users table in my database. If the user is found in the database, log them in with the found credentials. If not, store their user data and login them in.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED most probably means that there was an error on the backend that caused the server to restart. can you please copy the error from terminal here

Comment: @teleaziz That error comes from the browser console. I'm using Google Chrome. The terminal error is pictured in the OP. I thought at first it was a busy port issue, but that doesn't seem to be the case, though I could be wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're using the node-postgres module pg , pg.query accepts callbacks so lets take advantage of this feature and actually seperate the concern:

also I really recommend using the [passport-github2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-github2) module for github oauth strategy is mainatined and up to date:

```
var findByGithubId= function(githubId, callback) {
  return db.query('SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE github_id = $1', [githubId], callback);
};
```

And create:

```
var createOne = function(username, githubId, callback){
  return  db.query("INSERT INTO users (username, github_id) VALUES ($1, $2)", [username, githubId], callback);
};
```

Define the passport handler for github:

```
var passportGithubHandler = function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  findByGithubId( profile._json.id, function(err, user) {
    if (!user) {
      createOne(profile._json.name , profile._json.id , function(err, result){
        if (err) done(err);
        user= result.rows[0]; // not sure about this one please investigate, console.log might help 
        return done(err, user);
      })
    } else {
      return done(err, user);
    }
  });
};
```

Pass the handler :

```
passport.use(new GitHubStrategy({
  clientID: GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL:"http://localhost:5000/auth/github/callback"
},
passportGithubHandler));
```

Then define the route to authenticate

```
app.get('/auth/github',
  passport.authenticate('github'));
```

And the callback route

```
app.get('/auth/github/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('github', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
      // render or redirect or do whatever you have access to req.user now
    res.redirect('/'); 
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this breakdown. Using this code as is gives me a serialization error: `Failed to serialize user into session`. It looks like it's because my serialize handler doesn't handle the `github_id`, only the regular user id, but I'm unsure how I would modify this to make it work. Here's a [link](http://pastebin.com/kWNTXzTG) to my passport serialization code. Do I just add `user.github_id`?

Comment: EDIT: Found one issue. These handlers aren't authenticating anyone. I checked the database and no new users are there after running this code. Github also doesn't ask me to authorize the login. So I'm not sure at this point what happened.